# Redirecting to custom error page with web.xml and pretty-faces

Tags: jsf, custom-error-pages, prettyfaces

I've encountered an interesting issue with showing custom error pages to user when using PrettyFaces.

So, in my web application, I want to show a cute page with kitty and some relaxing words in case my app 'provides' any internal unexpected exception.
Here is a part of my `web.xml`:

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/pages/error/404.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
  <error-code>500</error-code>
  <location>/pages/error/500.xhtml</location>
</location>
```

And I've also tried general exception page (without error code and only `location` tag specified); it also doesn't work. Instead of showing cute kitty, ugly error 500 and stack trace incoming.

Another thing is that I'm using pretty-faces. So, I've tried this trick:
1) part of my `web.xml`

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>500</error-code>
  <location>/500</location>
</location>
```

2) part of my `pretty-config.xml`

```
<url-mapping id="404">
  <pattern value="/500" />
  <view-id value="/pages/error/500.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

This trick was better, but still doesn't do exactly what I want. Now it shows simple blank white page with nothing; and in browser console I can see requested URL with error code 404 (but the 500.xhtml file correctly exists, i can see it in assembled .ear).

Comment: What version of PrettyFaces are you using?

Comment: @Lincoln PrettyFaces version is 2.0.11 Final

Comment: Error pages aren't supposed to be idempotent in first place. You'd better take a step back and fix your custom exception handler as such that it does exactly the same as the container by default does: forwarding to it instead of redirecting to it.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your application, I'd have a hard time knowing what exactly is going on. There could be any number of reasons for this (a problem in the error page itself, for instance, that causes a subsequent exception that the container hides because it's already in error state.)

I would check to make sure that there is not a second exception being created when accessing the 500 page, as this is a common problem for exception pages that have any kind of functionality in them.

If you want more assistance, feel free to open a thread on http://ocpsoft.org/support/, upload an example app that reproduces this, and we can take a deeper look.